# How to remove White background from ggplot2 graph R Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am plotting graphs using ggplot2 in Shiny.  However, a white background exists around the plot, which I cannot remove.  Here is an image of what I am referring to.

[image]

Is it possible to remove this white background around the graph?  I've tried making it transparent, but that is not working, either.

```
        output$descrHistPlot <- renderPlot(ggplot(variableDataDescrPlots$dataMelted, aes(y = value)) + geom_histogram(bins = descrPlotsBins$bins, fill = "grey", color = "black") +
                                             facet_wrap(~variable) + coord_flip() + ggtitle(paste0("Histogram of ", input$menuDescrPlots[[1]], " Variables")) +
                                             theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.50), face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
                                             theme(axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.25), face = "bold")) +
                                             theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.25), face = "bold")) +
                                             theme(panel.grid.major  = element_line(color = "white"), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"),
                                                   panel.border = element_rect(color = "blue", fill = NA)) +
                                             theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 11, colour = "blue", face = "bold")))
```

Code like this

```
+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA))
```

does not work, as that white area is not part of the background.  Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the `plot.background` to transparent.

```
+ theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA))
```

Or you can match your background to your shiny background.

```
+   theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#ECF0F5"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to make the entire plot transparent, and nothing shows up:)  Maybe I'll try to match the plot background and the Shiny background.